# Set a taxonomy as private

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I created the taxonomy VAT and set public to false. But in frontend I can get posts by .../?vat_tax=22.
How can reserve this taxonomy anly for internal use?
Below the code I created for this taxonomy.

```
add_action( 'init', 'gp_register_taxonomy_vat' );
function gp_register_taxonomy_vat() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'          => 'VAT',
        'singular_name' => 'VAT',
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'public'            => false,
        'rewrite'           => false,
        'hierarchical'      => false,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'vat_tax', '', $args );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should also set the query_var to false.
So your args array should be like this:

```
$args = array(
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'public'            => false,
    'query_var'         => false,
    'rewrite'           => false,
    'hierarchical'      => false,
);
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried this solution but I can list posts by .../?taxonomy=vat_tax&term=22. I could add this value as post meta but I have only 3 values for VAT (4, 10, 22) and I think that a non hierarchical category is the best choice. In my single.php page I use a loop to print between taxonomies and terms attached to the post. I could eliminate taxonomies that have query_var set to false?